# Scrolling a ScrollViewer when Expander is expanded

Tags: wpf, mvvm, scroll, expander

I have a WPF MVVM application, in which ScrollViewer contains a user control with multiple Expanders

```
<UserControl>   
    <Expander>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                ...               
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Expander Grid.Row="0" />

            <Expander Grid.Row="1" />
            ... 

        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</UserControl>
```

How could I make expanded Expander to scroll into view so it's content is visible?

Comment: Did you try giving it a header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handle the `Expanded.Expanded` event in the code behind of the usercontrol and then call `Expander.BringIntoView()'.

Note: there's nothing wrong with using code behind for VIEW-specific things, and thus this does not break MVVM, IMO.

Comment: That worked, thanks. But I used BringIntoView(Rect), because BringIntoView() brings into view only its header.